# Using putExtra to pass values to intent service

Tags: java, android, android-intent

within my main activity I have the following code:

```
EditText usernameText;
EditText passwordText;
public void sendLogin (View loginview){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NetworkService.class);
    startService(i);
}
```

Currently, this just sends an intent to the NetworkService, which is handled as follows (truncated):

```
public class NetworkService extends IntentService {

    public NetworkService() {
        super("NetworkService");
    }

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent i) {

        /* HTTP CONNECTION STUFF */

        String login = URLEncoder.encode("Username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("XXX", "UTF-8");
        login += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("XXX", "UTF-8"); 
    }
}
```

Now, what I need to figure out, is how to pass those `usernameText` and `passwordText` values through to the `NetworkService` into the 'XXX', but ALSO within the `NetworkService`, I intend (no pun intended), to have it handle multiple intents from various places, one from a login, one from retrieving some information on users using the logon token, for instance. 
It's where all my networking will be contained. I was instructed this was the best practise within android applications, to keep the networking separate.

My question is: What is the best way of sending those two variables to the `NetworkService` and also how, within the `onHandleIntent` of the `NetworkService`, do I separate the code to only do what I'm asking it to (login, fetch user information, fetch location data etc)?

Sorry if the answer is a simple one, but I'm very new to application programming.

Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
public void sendLogin (View loginview){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NetworkService.class);
    i.putExtra("username", usernameText.getText().toString());
    i.putExtra("password", passwordText.getText().toString());
    startService(i);
}
```

Then in your IntentService:

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
    String password = intent.getStringExtra("password");
    ...
}
```

IntentServices are designed to handle several requests sent to it. In other words, if you keep sending intents using `startService(intent)`, your NetworkService will keep getting its `onHandleIntent` method called. Under the hood, it has a queue of intents that it will work through until it is finished. So if you keep sending intents the way you are currently, but with certain flags set through the `putExtra` methods, then you can detect what your NetworkService should do and act appropriately. e.g. set a boolean extra to your intent called `login`, in your intentservice look for that flag being set via `intent.getBooleanExtra("login")`. If true, do your login stuff, else look for other flags you set.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I'm after, I'm assigning each of the methods an 'intentID' int value via the putExtra, that I look for within the onhandleintent, to decide which part of the intent to execute. Only issue I'm having is the code hangs on the i.putExtra("username", usernameText.getText().toString()); so I'm trying to debug that now.

Comment: what's the solution if i use `IntentService` with `PendingIntent.getService()`?

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer

Answer (score 7):

**1.** For **sending** `usernameText` and `passwordText` to `NetworkService` do this....

```
Intent i = new Intent(Your_Class_Name.this, NetworkService.class);
   i.putExtra("username", usernameText.getText().toString());
   i.putExtra("password", passwordText.getText().toString());
   startService(i);
```

**2.** To **receive the data** in `NetworkService` do this....

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
   String userName = intent.getExtras().getString("username");
   String password = intent.getExtras().getString("password");
```

Comment: Why not call `intent.getStringExtra`??