# Android. The intent only the first time send what I want. Why?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, null, send

I use intent to send data from activity to other, when I call the 2nd activity repeatedly nothing happens,

The 1st intent:
`

```
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("1stNameIntent", firstName);
        intent.putExtra("2ndNameIntent", lastName);
        intent.putExtra("mailIntent", mail);
        intent.putExtra("mobileIntent", mobile);
        intent.putExtra("idIntent", intId);
        startActivity(intent);`
```

//There is no problem with values
...

The 2nd activity:

...
`

```
    public String firstNameHint = null;
public String lastNameHint = null;
public String mailHint = null;
 public String mobileHint = null;
public int id;
public String idStr = null;`

`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

    idStr = getIntent().getExtras().getString("idIntent");

        id = Integer.parseInt(idStr);
    firstNameHint = getIntent().getExtras().getString("1stNameIntent");
    firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstName_ID);
    firstName.setText(firstNameHint);
    firstName.setHint(firstNameHint);

    lastNameHint = getIntent().getExtras().getString("2ndNameIntent");
    lastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastName_ID);
    lastName.setText(lastNameHint);
    lastName.setHint(lastNameHint);`
```

...

I cant find out the problem. After the first use of 2nd activity only the default values appears.

Comment: you mean when you launch 2nd activity for the first time it gives you right value and 2nd time not?

Comment: Yeah. At the 2nd time when I launch every value is null by default.

Comment: I can help if you can post the complete code for the 1st activity.Seems like you are having some problem while setting the values in 1st activity.

Comment: when the 1st activity is called for second time oncreate is not executed keep that in mind. Check activity life cycle to get more info. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your onCreate Activity is not being called twice, depending on the 'launchMode' of the activity.
Try setting text in your onStart method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

implement `onNewIntent(Intent i)` in your second activity.

If the second activity has already been created (as it has), any future new intents will go to this `onNewIntentMethod(...)`

So, pull out your intent reading code and the code to set views into another method, and have both onCreate and onNewIntent call this new method that actually does the work.

Answer (score 0):

use

intent i = getIntent();
stringvariable = i.getStringExtra("1stNameIntent");

see this [Using putExtra to pass values to intent service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881208/using-putextra-to-pass-values-to-intent-service)

Answer (score 0):

you should make sure that you are calling `putExtra()` every time you are starting the activity. because I think it only works with one intent.
also try adding `Log.d()` on the `onCreate()` of the second activity to know when it is called.