# Pass value to a Service, intentService or bindService?

Tags: java, android, service

I need to pass 3 float numbers to a service and at the end the service need to send me back 'true' or 'false' boolean value.

I read about the two but do not know what I need to use,
an example will be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by "at the end of the service" ?

Comment: I ment of the service. I just need to send back a boolean value from the service to the main activity so indicator virtual led will be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first Question : Passing para to intent service

[Using putExtra to pass values to intent service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11881636/3367754)

, and about send notification back to activity from intent service :

[Using ResultReceiver in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10266994/3367754)

or try to use Callbacks Interface in service and implement it on activity

```
// on intent service
private onGetNotification notify=(onGetNotification)contextOfActivity;

public interface onGetNotification {
    public setOnGetNotification(Boolean result);
}

// use when finish
public void endOfService(){
    notify.setOnGetNotification(true);
}
```

Hope That Help :)

Comment: Thanks Ramy, it looks good i will try that, if my service is activating a class, and this class is getting 3 parameters and calculates them, and at the end send back one result. did i still need to use your answer? something different?

Comment: @Hadar.S you can use ResultReceiver is better

Comment: Thank you Ramy, looks like a great solution. will try that.