# android getting a variable through intent inside an extended intentservice activity

Tags: android, variables, android-intent, intentservice

Title self explanatory, how can I do that?

I've tried classic intent method but the getIntent() part doesn't work inside my activity extends IntentService..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `getIntent()` from the IntentService.

You get the intent as a parameter when your IntentService starts running (with `onHandleIntent()`). You can then read the extras normally with `getStringExtra()`. Check the code below:

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String username = intent.getStringExtra("key_1");
    String password = intent.getStringExtra("key_2");
    // Code here ...
}
```

Check this link for more: [Using putExtra to pass values to intent service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881208/using-putextra-to-pass-values-to-intent-service)

Comment: The problem is, my variable's intent is called iii and the onHandle is (Intent intent) cause is an intent to deal with notification, indeed using `String from = iii.getStringExtra("notesArrayy");` inside the onHandle doesn't resolve iii, so how am I suppose to move? thanks

Comment: Calling intent.getStringExtra() inside your onHandleIntent would reference to your original iii Intent. Java is just renaming your Intent, but the reference is the same. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value for more.